# sed delete block

Tags: regex, sed

Can you help me with deleting some block from dhcp config file using sed. 
File looks like:

```
host dev1 {
  host-identifier option agent.circuit-id "test1:418";
  fixed-address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  option routers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  option subnet-mask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
}
host host2{
  host-identifier option agent.circuit-id "test2-:5";
  fixed-address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  option routers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  option subnet-mask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
}
```

I should delete block for host matched by circuit-id. I did it by command:

```
sed -e '/^host\s*\S*\s*{\s*/ { N; /\s*test1:418/ { N; /[^host]/ { N; /[^host]/ { N; /[^host]/ { N; /[^host]/d}}}}}' -e '/^$/d' /path/to/file
```

But it doesn't seem acceptable at all...:(

Comment: `[^host]` matches a single character which is not `h`, `o`, `s`, or `t`. Every line in your sample contains at least one character which is not one of those, so every line matches this condition.

Comment: Many `sed` dialects also don't support Perl extensions like `\s` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an isc dhcp server I strongly recommend to use [`omshell`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/omshell) to modify the config.

Otherwise, if you have GNU `gawk`, the following `gawk` command might be good enough for you:

```
gawk '!/test2-:5/' RS='}\n' ORS='}\n' file
          ^----------------------------------- ID goes here
```

The command is limited to GNU `gawk` because it using a multi line record separator.

Explanation:

Using `}\n` as the record separator, awk will process the file block by block instead the default line-wise mode. Meaning awk will see these records:

```
host dev1 {
  host-identifier option agent.circuit-id "test1:418";
  fixed-address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  option routers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  option subnet-mask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
```

and

```
host host2{
  host-identifier option agent.circuit-id "test2-:5";
  fixed-address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  option routers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  option subnet-mask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
```

On those records we apply the regular expression `!/test2-:5/`. The `!` in front negates the match. We don't need to specify more since awk will by default print the current record if the condition evaluates to `true`. Since the second record matches the pattern it will not get printed.

Using `\n}` also for the *output record separator* adds the closing bracket when printing.

---

Btw, with `sed` I would use a loop based on a label (`:a`). We slurp input starting from `/host .*{/` until the closing `}` and append all lines to the pattern buffer. Once the closing `}` is reached we check if the pattern buffer contains the ID. If it contains the id it will get deleted:

```
sed '/host .*{/{:a;N;/}/!ba;/test2-:5/d}' file
```

Comment: You're 100% correct this is not a job for sed. Just mention its gawk-specific due to the multi-char `RS` or lose the `\n` after the `}`.

Comment: I'm too used to gawk! Thanks. Btw, based on our discussion yesterday I've shortly changed my mind to `BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n}"} !/test2-:5/'` but then I thought the double `}` at the end of the `BEGIN` block might confuse the OP more than it helps. I personally would prefer that from now on in cases where the length of the command is not an issue like this.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, it isn't for sed but I must do it by sed. Don't ask why.:) Your answer is OK at all..

Comment: @perun_ Added a sed solution. Don't asking why ;)